# package.json not found in node:13-alpine docker container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I made 2 docker images from 2 folder in [this repo](https://github.com/Samar-080301/MernCrudApp). The dockerfile was:

```
FROM node:13-alpine
EXPOSE 5000
RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir -p /home/app
COPY . /home/app
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

But the docker logs showed that the `package.json` file was not found and hence the containers closed, I can't even enter the terminal of the containers to see the available files.

The error output is in the below image.

[image]

To reproduce the error, clone the repo and run `sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify the working directory in your dockerfile and that's why the `package.json` cannot be found.

Ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir

add WORKDIR before `RUN npm install`

```
WORKDIR /home/app
RUN npm install
```